# Wicket Push service doesn't work after back

Tags: java, wicket

I'm playing with the Wicketstuff Push project. Or push-timer to be more specific. And now I'm facing a problem with back-button support.

As you can see on the [usage](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Push#usage) page, the standard way of using the push service is installing a push node within a component's constructor.

```
public CustomPanel()  {
    // setup UI components ...

    IPushService pushService = TimerPushService.get();
    IPushNode<Message> pushNode = pushService.installNode(this, handler);
    pushService.connectToChannel(pushNode, channel);
}
```

Then you can push a message to the channel

```
IPushService pushService = TimerPushService.get();
pushService.publish(channel, message);
```

It works perfectly until you change window location in your browser to some other url and then press back button. Wicket takes the page from its page map and renders it. Of course, your component's constructor is not called because the component hierarchy is reused. But it means the push service doesn't know about your component and pushing doesn't work anymore.

Is there any better way how to use the Push service? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Wicketstuff Push has API to check whether the current page is connected then you can move the registration code in onConfigure() method. It is called for each page rendering.